# Sentence Structure - It..Where / The place / That

Tags: sentence-construction

Here'a sentences written in my textbook.

> Hello, I'm staying in roon 124. I've got a problem and I was wondering if you could help me. I seem to have misplaced my wallet somewhere; it could have been in the hotel.

'it could have been in the hotel' doesn't sound enough because of omitting subject. So, what if I change into followings to make it sound fully?

> 1. It could have been in the hotel WHERE I misplaced my wallet.
> 2. It could have been in the hotel THAT I misplaced my wallet.
> 3. THE PLACE where I misplaced my wallet could have been in the hotel.

Are all of the three sentences right?

Comment: The original sentence is perfectly fine... the semicolon tells you that the independent clauses are closely related, in this case about the wallet. https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html There's no grammatical need to repeat the topic.

Comment: Thanky you @Catija Then 3 sentences are still fine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is actually perfectly fine due to the usage of the [semicolon](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html).

> Link two independent clauses to connect closely related ideas:
>
> - The cow is brown; it is also old.

So, in this example, the semicolon links the wallet as the topic of discussion in both independent clauses.

As to your sentences, while I don't believe they're grammatically incorrect, they all sound overly complicated.

As an AmE speaker, I'd say the more common statement would be something like:

> I may have misplaced my wallet in the hotel.
>
> I could have misplaced my wallet in the hotel.

Comment: @jihoon Welcome, Added second option to show that it's not the **could** that's clunky.